# Java: Get Source File Path

Tags: java, file, self-reference

I am trying to read from the source file in which the method is located. Ex. Method `readFromSrcFile()` needs to read from its own source file which can be `foobar.java`. How do I get the path of this `foobar.java` without hard coding it in?

Comment: You can't. There is no `foobar.java` when you run the application, only `foobar.class`. You'll have to have out-of-band knowledge of its location.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Could you provide some more context?